# R arrange list of vectors

Tags: r, list, sorting, vector

Say I have a list of vectors like this:

```
list.of.vec <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4)) %>% 
  mutate(a = list(list(c(1,2,3), c(2,3,4)), list(c(2,4,5), c(1,3,4)), list(c(1,2,3), c(4,3,4)), list(c(3,2,3), c(2,3,4))))
```

how can I arrange *a* such that in each pair of vectors, the one with the bigger first values goes first? E.g., if there was a list c(1,2,3), c(2,3,4), it should become c(2,3,4), c(1,2,3). And if first values are equal then it looks at the next value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use -

```
list.of.vec$a <- lapply(list.of.vec$a, function(x) {
  inds <- match(TRUE, x[[1]] != x[[2]])
  if(x[[1]][inds] > x[[2]][inds]) x else rev(x)
})

list.of.vec$a

#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 2 3 4

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3


#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] 2 4 5

#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] 1 3 4


#[[3]]
#[[3]][[1]]
#[1] 4 3 4

#[[3]][[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3


#[[4]]
#[[4]][[1]]
#[1] 3 2 3

#[[4]][[2]]
#[1] 2 3 4
```

`inds` would return the index for each list that we need to compare, an index where the value is different in both the vectors. If the first index has a higher value we return the list as it is without any change or else we return the reversed list.

Comment: A little word of explanation might be in order given the multiple margins addressed across `asplit` and `apply`.

Comment: It seems like this solution reorders values instead of vectors. e.g., in the last vector, the result should be c(3,2,3), c(2,3,4), but it is c(3, 3, 4), c(2,2,3)

Comment: @Chris Turns out that I had misunderstood the question earlier. I have updated the answer to correct it and also include some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rrapply`

```
library(rrapply)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
list.of.vec <- list.of.vec %>%
     mutate(a = map(a, ~ .x[order(-rrapply(.x, f = function(x) x[1], 
          how = 'unlist'))]))
```

-output

```
> list.of.vec
  id                a
1  1 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3
2  2 2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4
3  3 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3
4  4 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4

> list.of.vec$a
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 1 2 3


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 2 4 5

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 1 3 4


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 4 3 4

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 1 2 3


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] 3 2 3

[[4]][[2]]
[1] 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
lapply(
  a,
  function(x) {
    x[order(-sapply(x, `[`, 1))]
  }
)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 1 2 3


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 2 4 5

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 1 3 4


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 4 3 4

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 1 2 3


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] 3 2 3

[[4]][[2]]
[1] 2 3 4
```